# Site won't display messages

Tags: status-messages

I'm desperate.
I have a site with 2 databases, staging and production, and in staging messages set with drupal_set_messages() appear, but in production they don't.
The codebase is the same. I tried switching database settings on the same codebase and the behavior will change depending on the database.
I have inherited the site so I'm not 100% familiar with its configuration.

My question is: is there anything on a database level that can block messages from showing? They appear in the admin area, but not in the rest of the website...

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! I assume the theme used in both the cases is the same, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

`Configuration > Development > Logging and errors` has some settings on whether to display drupal messages or not. You might check to make sure that it is properly configured for your use case.

Path to config page: /admin/config/development/logging

Comment: I had already tried that, but there was no difference. I tried looking around, and MAYBE the problem is about one database lacking the user with ID = 0, which drupal uses for anonymous users. The session data isn't stored correctly, so messages don't persist in the $_SESSION variable. I'm not sure and I will test this on monday at work, but I'm hopeful this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check your module page. There are modules such as Disable messages. Is any such module enabled on production.